# Restrict user access to azure ressources when using native application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

My problem is the following: I need my users to be able to access some service in azure based on their group.

For instance we use batch service. I created a resource group dedicated to a group of users, created a batch service inside it and defined the group of users as contributor of the resource group.

If users log in the portal, they can manage their batch service and only this one. Users not in the group don't have access to this resource and that's fine.

Now suppose I want to do the same from a desktop app. 
First I need the users to aquire a token to be authorized to use the services:

```
private static string GetAuthenticationTokenWithLogin(BatchAccount account)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(account.AuthorityUri);
    var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(batchUri, account.ClientId, new Uri(account.RedirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
    authResult.Wait();
    return authResult.Result.AccessToken;
}
```

Then the user is seen as the application defined by RedirectUri and has authorizations corresponding to this application.

If I create in azure an application as a Web app / API, I can then set a precise group of users as allowed on it but the above login code does not work. I get:

```
The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'
```

If I create an application as Native, the above code works fine but I can't set a specific group of users on the application (so everyone in my Azure AD has access to the service).

How can I have both an authentication by user using their own login and the possibility to restrict user access?

Comment: Hmm, so even though the user is granted no role on the Batch service, they can still login to your native app and call it? Could it be Batch is not checking the user other than that they are from the right tenant? Because if so, you might have to build a proxy service in front of it.

Comment: People log in the app and then batch service checks app authorization. What I would like to do is restrict log in to the app to limited group of users to indirectly restrict access to batch service. I would have preferred to not use any app at all but batch API require passing through an app.

Comment: Hmm, well since you can't assign users to roles on a native app, it might be impossible at the moment.

Comment: Would there be any other way rather than all or nothing? It just seems crazy

Comment: Nothing comes to my mind. Hopefully someone with an idea comes along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to understand how it works and as it took me a lot of digging I thought of posting the answer here.

At first I was using a native app which I was using without any login. Instead I was using the application key to automatically be identified as the app. In the case, I had to add the app as contributor of my service. This worked fine but was not perfect for security reasons (I had to share the credentials to the app and every users with those credentials could access the service). The important thing in this case is that everything is done under the app identity.

When switching to user login, I thought I still had to add the app as a contributor to the service but that was not the case. As mentionned in the comment above, I can't specify authorized users on the app. 
Instead, once logged in, the users keep their identity (they are not using the app identity). This means I don't have to add the app as a contributor to the resource anymore and if a user without the proper IAM role tries to use the service through the app, he will just get refused.

In conclusion:

- Create a native app.
- Give it access to the service you want (the generic service like "https://batch.core.windows.net/", not your specific resource)
- Give you users (or group of user) a IAM role corresponding to their activity (Reader, Contributor)
- Use code in the question to authenticate